# Logging Into AliBaba.com programmatically

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to figure out how to login to the website https://login.alibaba.com using PHP and CURL.  I am using the code below but it does not seem to be working.  How would you recommend I login to this site automatically?

My current code:

```
<?
$cookie = "cookie.txt";
// set global curl options
$curloptions = array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6',
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie,
        CURLOPT_REFERER => 'http://www.alibaba.com'
);

// set userinfo
$username = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$password = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

// clear cookie.txt (fresh session)
$handle = fopen($cookie, 'w');
fclose($handle);

// make a dummy request to generate a session
curl_http_request('https://login.alibaba.com', $curloptions);

// login
curl_http_request('https://login.alibaba.com', 
    array(
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'xloginPassport=' . $username . '&xloginPassword=' . $password . '&noCsrfToken=&xloginCheckToken=&rememberme=&runatm=',
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE
    ), $curloptions
);

//example request
echo curl_http_request('https://login.alibaba.com', 
    array(
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
    ), $curloptions
);

function curl_http_request ($url, $moreoptions = array(), $options = array())
{
    foreach ($moreoptions as $k => $v) $options[$k] = $v;
  $handle = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt_array($handle, $options);
  ob_start();
  $buffer = curl_exec($handle);
  ob_end_clean();
  curl_close($handle);
  return $buffer;
}
?>
```

Comment: If you have a good reason to access them programmatically, probably best to contact them and enquire about whether they provide supported API access. Much better than trying to hack around protection which has obviously been developed specifically to stop the kind of thing you are wanting to do...

Comment: did you get it to work? im looking for the same

Comment: is there any way to do this ? they preventing bots or spiders from crawling and downloading data.

Answer (score 0):

They are using some token generation method on login, so unless you know how to generate the same, just use their web login.

Here's a typical login request looks like:

> https://login.alibaba.com/xman/xlogin.js?pd=alibaba&pageFrom=standardlogin&u_token=Bf0323500b707423d50c96aae931e204b&xloginPassport=andreaswongg70&xloginPassword=10fd852ff6603865cf632b59d935e56b&dmtrack_pageid=ca1b1fe2cdcc700d4f66917813628a849a71fcca49

Comment: Okay cool thanks how would I store the cookie so I can run my script and it will see me logged in?

Comment: My answer wasn't about the cookie, but they have a unique token generation on every login attempt, so unless you can guess the token at that point of time your script is running, just stick to web login.

Comment: Okay well it's not allowing me to login...I keep getting the result: var xlogin_failed={"error_type":"illegal_password","check_token":"no"}